# m.request: Determine specific cause of XHR Failure?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, mithril.js

#### Question

When mithril's `m.request` fails with a timeout or a network error, the error returned is simply `null`.  This makes it impossible to distinguish between

1. timeouts
2. a lack of internet connection
3. other kinds of errors.

Is there a way to determine this information?

#### Demo

In the snippet below, the request will timeout every time, since the limit is 1ms. The error returned is `null`.  If you change it to 1000ms, it will work.  If you turn your wifi off, and try again, it will return another `null` error.

```js
const Test = {
  controller: function() {

    var user = m.prop('Waiting...');
    var error = m.prop();

    var args = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
      config: function(xhr) {
        xhr.timeout = 1;
      }
    };

    function refreshUser() {
      m.request(args)
       .then( users => user(users[0].name), error);
    }
    return { user, error, refreshUser};
  },
  view: function(ctrl) {
    return m('div', [
      m('div',  'Fetched User: ' + ctrl.user()),
      m('div', 'Network Error: ' + ctrl.error()),
      m('button', {onclick: ctrl.refreshUser }, 'Refresh User')
    ]); 
  }
}
m.mount(document.body, Test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mithril/0.2.5/mithril.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a parameter you can pass to `m.request` called `extract`, which will contain the xhr response. Hopefully you can find what you need there.

Example from the [m.request docs](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.request.html#extracting-metadata-from-the-response):

```
var extract = function(xhr, xhrOptions) {
    if (xhrOptions.method == "HEAD") return xhr.getResponseHeader("x-item-count")
    else return xhr.responseText
}

m.request({method: "POST", url: "/foo", extract: extract});
```